# Citing ROS in a scientific article

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it obligatory to quote ROS when mentioned in a scientific article? Is there a strict rule on this matter?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401394/citing-ros-in-a-scientific-article/) by [Grigoriy_Y](https://answers.ros.org/users/70870/grigoriy_y/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends, at least for me.

If it's an important part of your research (e.g. you prepared a special protocol for experimental validation of results, used some packages from ROS toolkit, etc.), then you should mention it by citing the [ICRA 2009 article](http://robotics.stanford.edu/%7Eang/papers/icraoss09-ROS.pdf)

or at least by giving a site link like this:

`Open Source Robotics Foundation. Robotic Operating System.\url{https://www.ros.org}`

If it was used somewhere on your robot, but wasn't important to the overall publication, I would skip it (but it should be in the project documentation beyond those few pages in the journal).

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2